# How do I eliminate large spaces in a stylized output?

Tags: javascript, css, formatting

I am in a coding class and am working on a FizzBuzz problem in JScript. I have white spaces appearing where I inserted my  tags for color.

I tried highlighting the output text and these are not space characters, but rather just emptiness. I tried removing the  tags from my code and that removed the spaces, but I put the tags in there to change the color and I'd like to keep them looking like that.

```
output = output.substr(0, output.length - 2);
$("#fbout").html(output + "");



    return "<span class='fizzbuzz'>FizzBuzz</span>, ";
}
else if (numcompare % fizzy == 0) {
    return "<span class='fizz'>Fizz</span>, ";
}
else if (numcompare % buzzy == 0) {
    return "<span class='buzz'>Buzz</span>, ";
}
```

I expected the output to have a single space after each comma, but I am getting the large empty space leading into each instance of Fizz, Buzz, and FizzBuzz.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more code than that. All you gave us was the returned HTML, but you're not giving us the part that actually adds it to the DOM.

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code, but there are still essential parts missing.

Comment: Ok, I've added a bit more. I hope it's what you needed. I'm still pretty new at this...